# AutoCAD: Registering a plugin for all users

Tags: plugins, autocad

We have a legacy AutoCAD plugin for integration with our applicaton.

The plugin uses ARX and an acad.lsp file to load itself on startup. The plugin installer adds the plugin directory to the ACAD support path in the registry under HKCU...\General\ACAD.

The problem with this approach is that modifying the support path under HKCU only affects the current user. Iterating over all profiles and adding the support path to each of them seems to be a bad approach as pointed out in Raymond Chen's [Beware of roaming user profiles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/30/434209.aspx). This also leaves out new users, whose profiles have not yet been created on the machine at the time of installation.

Therefore I'm looking for a way to register an AutoCAD plugin for all users upon installation, be it a global support path or some other way of registration.

The plugin should work on AutoCAD 2006 through 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/09/automatic_loadi.html